# How do I deploy azure funtion app packaged as .nugpk using azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a build pipeline that generates .nupkg for azure function, when I try to release it the content gets deployed (I can see when I download the app content) but I cannot see the function.

Is it the case that azure artifact has to be .zip for azure function? I am able to deploy the angular and .net core app using .nupkg without any problem!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the case that azure artifact has to be .zip for azure function?

You re right.

Currently, only `.zip` package files are supported.

That because:

> Zip deployment is a feature of Azure App Service that lets you deploy
>   your function app project to the wwwroot directory. The project is
>   packaged as a `.zip` deployment file. **The same APIs can be used to
>   deploy your package to the d:\home\data\SitePackages folder**. With
>   the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` app setting value of 1, the zip
>   deployment APIs copy your package to the `d:\home\data\SitePackages`
>   folder instead of extracting the files to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`.

You could check the document [Run your Azure Functions from a package file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package) for some details.

And there is state about that:

[image]

Hope this helps.